# How override non virtual method?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I have base class with virtual method. And I have child class, which has override this method. Then I have child of child, but how I can override the same method? If I try to add 'virtual' to second class, I get message: 'Override method cannot be marked as virtual'. If I try to add 'override' to third class I get message: 'This is no suitable method for override'.

How to resolve this issue?

I can inherit third class from first, but actually I'd like to have some methods from second class.

```
public virtual T Save (T entity)
        {
            //removed code

            return entity;
        }

public override T Save(T entity)
        {
            //removed code

            return entity;
        }

 public T Save(T entity)
        {
            return entity;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please show all three signatures?

Comment: Specifying `override` on the child should work just fine.  Are you sure the signature is the same?  Can you post the method in question from each class?

Comment: added code (in question)

Comment: @Alex - That's really strange.  Are you sure that the third class actually inherits from the second?  Because that really should work.

Comment: Okay, just found misspelling error in third class declaration. Now override is working.

Comment: That would definitely do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just override it (in the "child of child").  Overriding methods are implicitly virtual.

Comment: but if I can't add override?

Comment: What do you mean, if you "can't add override"?

Comment: I had error message if I tried to add it. Actually class declaration was incorrect, when I fixed it, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

All [`overridden methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645768%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are implicitly virtual. OVERRIDE THEM ALL!!!!